# MonoTouch FinishedLaunching Method App Gets Killed

Tags: c#, iphone, multithreading, xamarin.ios

My application gets killed due to on FinishedLaunching method is the heavy lifting of my app, my question is how can populate my application of data that comes from a web service without user interaction, i mean the data must come from the WS to the device so the application is usable.

Is there any way to create a new thread or a backgroundworker so FinishedLaunching can return, but the iphone on the background still be contacting the web service and downloading the needed data??

an example would be very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use C# asynchronous invocation, works in MonoTouch the way it should:

```
new Action(this.FetchDataFromWS).BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

But the best practice would be to get the data from the web service when your main view loads, not in FinishedLaunching.

Comment: And what about if i want to display a "Loading modal view"? i got the modal view code but i dont know how to display it without the app getting freezed by the WS download

Comment: In the same C# manner. Bare in mind though that since you want something to do with the UI, you will have to execute it on the main thread, just like WinForms, so inside FinishedLaunching: new Action(this.LoadModalView).BeginInvoke(null, null); and inside the "LoadModalView" method, wrap your code with this.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(delegate { //bla bla; });.

Comment: Again of course, I do not suggest that you should do it in FinishedLaunching but in the first view controller that loads.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar vein to [@Dimitris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848049/monotouch-finishedlaunching-method-app-gets-killed/4848895#4848895), though I am addicted to the syntactic sugar you get this way, you can spin off a lambda with the (Task Parallel Library)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx]. Tasks also have all sorts of fantastic continuation, context, and error handling opportunities.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    FetchDataFromWS();
});
```

I had similar code in my Main.cs `FinishedLoading` method. When I hit a breakpoint in a debug run and then got side-tracked and ran off to lunch, it was still waiting on me when I got back because `FinishedLoading` had long since returned. Fair warning: I haven't done anything real-world with this yet.